# TFS 2015 - Authentication between domain failed

Tags: authentication, tfs, active-directory, tfs-2015

My organization is going to migrate all user from domain A to domain B, so they replicate all users from domain A to domain B. For example, if DomainA\User1 exists, then it will be copied over to domain B, DomainB\User1, same password is replicated.

Right now, in TFS, there is only DomainA\User1.

2 ways trust between domain A and domain B have been set up, but when I attempt to access TFS server via Visual Studio, using DomainB\User1, the authentication fails.

Is there any additional steps I need to do to accomplish this? I thought that if I have 2 ways trust between domain, I can sign in using same user account from domain B as long as the user in domain A exist in TFS server.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you run the `TFSConfig Identities /change /fromdomain:OldDomainName /todomain:NewDomainName` command? Before run the command, make sure the domainB accounts are not added to TFS.  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/move-across-domains#move-tfs-user-and-service-accounts